# Comparing values of a range of cells to a single cell's value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to compare values of a range of cells to a single cell's value. I want to know if any cell's value of the range is smaller.

Example:

A1 : 1
A2 : 5
A3 : 7
A4 : 9

B1 : 2

I could use this formula:

```
=IF(OR(A1<B1,A2<B1,A3<B1,A4<B1),0,B1)
```

It does what I need. But I'm looking for a more elegant and practical formula than OR because I need to check a range of more than 100 cells.

Which formula do I use?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: COUNTIF worked fine but now I want to compare a range of values in the same row of 2 columns to a single cell.

Example:

A1 : 1
A2 : 5
A3 : 7

B1 : 2
B2 : 3
B3 : 6

C1 : 11

```
=IF(OR(AND(A1<C1,B1>C1),AND(A2<C1,B2>C1),AND(A3<C1,B3>C1)),0,C1)
```

COUNTIF just checks if any cell within and the range is smaller or larger. It doesn't match the rows though.

Comment: `=if(countif(a1:a4, "<"&b1), 0, b1)`

Comment: `=IF(B1<SMALL(A1:A4,1),B1,0)`

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the minimum value of column A in a cell and compare it to value in B1.

```
=IF(MIN(A1:A4)<B1,0,B1)
```